# Slice every string in list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, slice

I want to slice every string in a list in Python.

This is my current list:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
```

This is the list I want for result:

```
['O', 'T', 'Thr', 'Fo', 'Fi']
```

I want to slice away the two last characters from every single string in my list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please try to demonstrate minimal efforts before you ask for a solution.

Comment: Can you slice the last two characters from a string?

Comment: I think we should discourage this kind of questions by not providing ready solution, this won't be really helping OP, at least not for his future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list with the result of an expression applied to each element in the inputlist; here the `[:-2]` slices of the last two characters, returning the remainder:

```
[w[:-2] for w in list_of_words]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_words = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
>>> [w[:-2] for w in list_of_words]
['O', 'T', 'Thr', 'Fo', 'Fi']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
>>> l = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'] 
>>> [i[:-2] for i in l]
['O', 'T', 'Thr', 'Fo', 'Fi']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
print map(lambda i:i[:-2],x)  #for python 2.7
print list(map(lambda i:i[:-2],x)) #for python 3
```