# Slicing strings

Tags: python, list, slice

In python, I want to slice strings in a list in such a way that first few characters from that list must be removed/spliced out.

```
a=['hello', 'things', 'becoming', 'expensive']
```

How I can remove the first two characters from each string in the list to get the output

`['llo', 'ings', 'coming', 'pensive']`

Comment: Use list comprehension: `a = [s[2:] for s in a]   # ['llo', 'ings', 'coming', 'pensive']`

Comment: First read [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2745495) then read [Slice every string in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314886/slice-every-string-in-list-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

```
a=['hello', 'things', 'becoming', 'expensive']
b = []

for word in a:
    b.append(word[2:])


print(b)
```

Results in:

```
['llo', 'ings', 'coming', 'pensive']
```

This piece:

```
word[2:]
```

is saying to start at Index 2 and return everything to the right of it. Indexes start at 0, so the first 2 letters are ignored

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it, but the idea behind is the same, treating the string as a sequence of characters and taking from the 3rd one (index 2, as lists start from 0) until the end, using the `:` range notation.

Iteratively:

```py
for idx, word in enumerate(a):
    a[idx] = word[2:]
```

Comprehension List:

```py
a = [word[2:] for word in a]
```

Map

```py
a = list(map(lambda word: word[2:], a))
```

Possibly, there are other ways, but these are the most common.

Answer (score 1):

```
a =['hello', 'things', 'becoming', 'expensive']
for char in  a :
    a[a.index(char)] = char[2:]
print(a)
```

Comment: Instead of `a.index(char)`, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate): `for idx, char in enumerate(a):`

Comment: Yeah,it has lot of solution,but this cod is easier.

Comment: Thank you, Payam and all others for this wonderful answer. It really worked for me, However, I wonder, why I can't use the same code if all the strings in this list were multiline strings? What would be the modification in this code then????

Comment: Thank you, Payam and all others for this wonderful answer. It really worked for me, However, I wonder, why I can't use the same code if all the strings in this list were multiline strings? What would be the modification in this code then????